# Open image that user clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two images. However, when I click to open one, it opens both. In addition, I made a code that takes the image that has the same src, but when opening one, it opens two identical images. I want you to open only one and exclusively the one the user clicked on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img-min').on("click", function() {
    // $(this).toggleClass('img-max')
    const min = $(this).attr('src');
    const max = $('img').attr('src', min);
    $('div').removeClass('hide');
    $('#close-img').removeClass('hide');
    $("body").addClass("sem-scroll");
  });
})
```

```css
.img-min {
  height: auto;
  width: 10%;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.hide:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sem-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center hide" id="openImg">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img class="img-max" src="images/jbproducts1.png">
    <img class="img-max" src="images/logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
<h1 class="text-center mb-5">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<div id="div-icon" class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img class="img-min" src="images/jbproducts1.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-min" src="images/logo.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
const max = $('img').attr('src', min);
```

Changes all img tags' src attributes to the same value (const min). That is why you have two identical images.

With selector `$('img.img-max[src="'+min+'"]')` you should get only the img-max element with correct src. Then shiw only that element and hide others.

Comment: I moved to `const max = $('.img-max').attr('src', min);`. Not work.

Comment: That effectively does the same thing.

Comment: The attr-function changes the attribut. You should use correct selector. See my edits (sorry, on mobile so they might be little off).

Comment: Smoothly. Anyway, it doesn't work. He takes the two different images

Comment: I am afraid you have more issues in your code. Use the browser debugger tools and try to find the correct selector so that you only control the desired html element.

Comment: For example not anywhere in the original code do you hide all/other img-max elements. You just unhide everything.